# How to delete/suspend a process instance in Activiti programmatically?

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I created a Process Engine, Repository Service, Runtime Service and deployed a BPMN workflow.
I also created a Process instance and was able to start it.
The issue is that when I try to either suspend or delete the process instance using the "deleteProcessInstance" method I get an error saying that the ProcessInstanceId could not be found!!
PS: I learnt somewhere that the processId in BPMN is treated as processKey in Activiti.

Code:

```
public void startProcess(String processDefinitionKey)
{
    ListenerClass.processInstance=ListenerClass.runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processDefinitionKey);
}

public void deleteProcess(String processInstanceId)
{
    System.out.println("Stopping Process instance id " +processInstanceId);
    ListenerClass.runtimeService.deleteProcessInstance(processInstanceId, "Ok");
}
```

In the code above while starting the process instance, I pass the "Process Id" of the BPMN.xml file.(which means processId of BPMN.xml=processInstanceKey of Activiti)

My BPMN.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" 
xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_1" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" 
targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn">
  <bpmn:process id="Process_11" isExecutable="true" name="Hima">
    <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_06sykhd</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>  
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_06sykhd" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="Task_1dt8brv" />
    <bpmn:endEvent id="EndEvent_0cb0ioi">
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1doj4n6</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:serviceTask id="Task_1dt8brv"
             name="My Java Service Task"
             activiti:class="com.bosch.bip.Service.task1" >
    
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_06sykhd</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_156te78</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:serviceTask>
    <bpmn:serviceTask id="Task_10bfll9" activiti:class="com.bosch.bip.Service.task1">
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_156te78</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1doj4n6</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:serviceTask>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_156te78" sourceRef="Task_1dt8brv" targetRef="Task_10bfll9" />
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1doj4n6" sourceRef="Task_10bfll9" targetRef="EndEvent_0cb0ioi" />
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="Process_11">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="173" y="102" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_06sykhd_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_06sykhd">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="209" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="264" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="264" y="147" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="318" y="147" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="219" y="123.5" width="90" height="20" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="EndEvent_0cb0ioi_di" bpmnElement="EndEvent_0cb0ioi">
        <dc:Bounds x="768" y="173" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="741" y="209" width="90" height="20" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Task_1dt8brv_di" bpmnElement="Task_1dt8brv">
        <dc:Bounds x="318" y="107" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Task_10bfll9_di" bpmnElement="Task_10bfll9">
        <dc:Bounds x="528" y="94" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_156te78_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_156te78">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="418" y="147" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="473" y="147" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="473" y="134" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="528" y="134" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="386" y="202.5" width="90" height="20" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_1doj4n6_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_1doj4n6">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="628" y="134" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="698" y="134" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="698" y="191" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="768" y="191" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="653" y="152.5" width="90" height="20" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

Any help in this regards would be really helpful.

Comment: The Activiti API doesn't have any method to delete a Process instance by "processkey"

Comment: ProcessInstanceId is not the same as processKey. Could you paste your code here?

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga I have edited my question. Please have a look

Comment: how does your processInstanceId parameter in deleteProcess() look like?

Answer (score 5):

For a running process use this, as you did above:

```
runtimeService.deleteProcessInstance(processInstanceId, null);
```

If the process has been ended you need to delete it from the history, maybe your process has already ended?

```
HistoricProcessInstance historicProcessInstance = historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery()
        .processInstanceId(processInstanceId).singleResult();
if (historicProcessInstance != null) {
    historyService.deleteHistoricProcessInstance(historicProcessInstance.getId());
}
```

Comment: The processInstanceId is "Process_11:1:4" as an example. I checked in the DB and I used this id to delete the process as you cited above but it throws me a null pointer exception

Comment: Also my requirement is to suspend a processInstance but when I use the API to suspend,even that fails as it is not able to fetch the processInstanceId

Comment: You took id from table ACT_RE_PROCDEF. It's not processInstanceId. ProcessInstanceId you can find in ACT_RU_EXECUTION. You can also find processInstanceId accessor in ProcessInstance object.

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga Is it that a record is created in the ACT_RU_EXECUTION table only when a processInstance is awaiting an action from another user? If yes then is there a way in which we can see/fetch the processInstance Id while it is executing(say printing numbers from 1-1000) and not awaiting an user action?Which table will it be available in?

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga Also when I suspend a processInstance, does that mean that the entire workflow fed as a BPMN model.xml stops executing immediately? And how to restart the suspended processInstance? Any API suggestion?